# mapSVG text objects floating in top left corner position

Tags: jquery, svg, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

I'm using [mapSVG](http://map.karaliki.ru/index.html) to render an SVG of some simple floor plans. I've positioned text objects over top of each shape to be used as labels for each unit (Unit 1, Unit 2, etc.)

I save the SVG out in Illustrator, and if I open the SVG directly with Firefox (for example), the shapes and text are all in the correct location. It looks how I want it to.

The problem happens when I render the SVG with the help of mapSVG and it's scripts. The shapes still look correct, but it appears as though all my text objects positioned on top of each other at 0,0 (top left corner).

Any idea why this would happen? I don't have an online link to provide at the moment but I will update when I do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I may have been doing this wrong. I don't know if it should work with text objects or not, but what I ended up doing was converting the text objects to outlines and then exporting them as paths along with the other unit shapes.

From there I just used the 'disable' option on the text paths (now outlines) for specific regions in mapSVG. This seems to have worked.